# "syntax error, unexpected '{' " after keyword 'finally' when run php cli

Tags: php, try-catch-finally

I met "*PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in* ..." error when I tried to execute PHP CLI script.

Error message:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in ??/test.php on line 9
```

Command:

```
php -f ./test.php
```

Code:

```
<?php
 echo 'begin'.PHP_EOL;

 try {
    echo 'try!'.PHP_EOL;
 } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'exception'.PHP_EOL;
 } finally{
    echo 'finally'.PHP_EOL;
 }
 echo 'end';
```

PHP version: `PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Aug  5 2016 07:50:38)`

Environment: `RedHat 7.3`

**This is a strange case, this script work well at my Windows PC, but got this issue in Redhat machine.**

Have someone once met this case as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need PHP 5.5 or later to use the finally block. Perhaps on the windows machine you have a later version of PHP?

Comment: Exactly! That's the point. I even don't know this is a feature after PHP 5.0!

Answer (score 1):

Finally keyword is only supported for PHP version 5.5 or greater

[PHP: Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)